# problema con la librería Djep de java en Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy utilizando una librería llamada Djep en java que resuelve funciones matemáticas, pero cuando ingreso una función con una raíz cuadra o cubica como por ejemplo: √(x^2)+1 -tan⁡(x) me sale error. Yo supongo que debe ser porque no reconoce el simbolo de la raiz "√".

Aquí le dejo un ejercicio en la cual si funciona:

función: e^-x^3 -1x +1
Limite A: 0.75
Limite B: 1
Error: 1
Decimales: Aquí ingresan la cantidad de decimales que desean trabajar

Aqui les dejo el codigo:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.brynner.mtodobiseccion;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import com.mikepenz.itemanimators.AlphaCrossFadeAnimator;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeader;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.AccountHeaderBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.DrawerBuilder;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AccountHeader headerResult = null;
    private Drawer result = null;
    private Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Handle Toolbar
    final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Create Header Drawer
    headerResult = new AccountHeaderBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withTranslucentStatusBar(true)
            .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.image_header_drawer_navigation)
            .build();

    //Create Drawer Layout
    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(toolbar)
            .withHasStableIds(true)
            .withItemAnimator(new AlphaCrossFadeAnimator())
            .withAccountHeader(headerResult)  //set the AccountHeader we created earlier for the header
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Biseccion").withIdentifier(1).withSelectable(true),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Falsa Posicion").withIdentifier(2).withSelectable(true),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Newton Raphson").withIdentifier(3).withSelectable(true)
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    switch ((int) drawerItem.getIdentifier()){
                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Biseccion.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReglaFalsa.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewtonRaphson.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .withShowDrawerUntilDraggedOpened(false)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
        result.closeDrawer();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

Metodos.java:

```
package com.example.brynner.mtodobiseccion;

import org.lsmp.djep.djep.DJep;
import org.nfunk.jep.Node;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Metodos {
    private DJep dJep;
    private String funcion;
    private boolean ban = false;

public String getFuncion() {
    return funcion;
}

public void setFuncion(String funcion) {
    this.funcion = funcion;
}

public Metodos(String funcion) {
    dJep = new DJep();
    this.funcion = funcion;
    dJep.addStandardConstants();
    dJep.addStandardFunctions();
    dJep.addComplex();
    dJep.setAllowUndeclared(true);
    dJep.setAllowAssignment(true);
    dJep.setImplicitMul(true);
    dJep.addStandardDiffRules();
}

public Double resolver(double x) throws ParseException, org.nfunk.jep.ParseException {
    Node nodo = null;
    String val="No";
    dJep.addVariable("x", x);
    try{
        nodo = dJep.parse(funcion);
    } catch (org.nfunk.jep.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    val = (dJep.evaluate(nodo)).toString();
    return Double.parseDouble(val);
}

public String derivar(){
    String derivada = "No";
    Node node = null;
    try {
        node = dJep.parse(funcion);
    } catch (org.nfunk.jep.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Node diff = null;
    try {
        diff = dJep.differentiate(node,"x");
    } catch (org.nfunk.jep.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Node simp = null;
    try {
        simp = dJep.simplify(diff);
    } catch (org.nfunk.jep.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    derivada = dJep.toString(simp);
    return derivada;
}
}
```

Biseccion.java:

```
package com.example.brynner.mtodobiseccion;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.nfunk.jep.ParseException;

public class Biseccion extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText_Funcion, editText_Error, editText_Decimales,                                 editText_LimiteA, editText_LimiteB;
    private Button button_Aceptar, button_Nuevo;
    private TextInputLayout textInputLayoutFuncion, textInputLayoutLimiteA,         textInputLayoutLimiteB, textInputLayoutError, textInputLayoutDecimales;
    private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    private Object [] columns = {"N", "X", "F(x)", "Y", "F(y)", "Xr", "F(Xr)", "F(Xr) * F(x)", "F(Xr) * F(y)", "Error"};
    private double a, aAnt, b, bAnt, xr, xrAnt, errorCalculado, fa, fb, fxr;
    private double [][] matriz = new double[columns.length][20];
    private int decimales, errorIngresado, n, filas;
    private boolean boolDiverge;
    private Metodos metodo;
    private Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_biseccion);
        initComponent();

    }

    public void initComponent(){
        textInputLayoutFuncion = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout_Funcion);
        textInputLayoutLimiteA = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout_LimiteA);
        textInputLayoutLimiteB = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout_LimiteB);
        textInputLayoutError = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout_Error);
        textInputLayoutDecimales =     findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout_Decimales);
        editText_Funcion = findViewById(R.id.edit_query_funcion);
        editText_LimiteA = findViewById(R.id.edit_query_limiteA);
        editText_LimiteB = findViewById(R.id.edit_query_limiteB);
        editText_Error = findViewById(R.id.edit_query_error);
        editText_Decimales = findViewById(R.id.edit_query_decimales);
        button_Aceptar = findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel_Aceptar);
        button_Nuevo = findViewById(R.id.buttonPanel_Nuevo);

        button_Aceptar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint({"ResourceAsColor", "ResourceType"})
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(validar() == false){
                    setErrorFalse();

                    initVariables();

                    resolverBiseccion();

                    if(boolDiverge == true){
                        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Biseccion.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Mensaje");
                        builder.setMessage("La función diverge. \n¿Desea ver el resultado?");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Si", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                intent = new Intent(Biseccion.this, ResultBiseccion.class);
                                intent.putExtra("matriz", matriz);
                                intent.putExtra("decimales", decimales);
                                intent.putExtra("filas", filas);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", new     DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();
                    }
                    else{
                        intent = new Intent(Biseccion.this,     ResultBiseccion.class);
                        intent.putExtra("matriz", matriz);
                        intent.putExtra("decimales", decimales);
                        intent.putExtra("filas", filas);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    button_Nuevo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setErrorFalse();
            clear();
        }
    });
}

public boolean verificarVacio(EditText editText){
    if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean validar(){
    if(verificarVacio(editText_Funcion) == false && verificarVacio(editText_LimiteA) == false && verificarVacio(editText_LimiteB) == false && verificarVacio(editText_Error) == false && verificarVacio(editText_Decimales) == false){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        if(verificarVacio(editText_Funcion) == true){
            textInputLayoutFuncion.setError("Campo vacio");
        }
        else{
            textInputLayoutFuncion.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        if(verificarVacio(editText_LimiteA) == true){
            textInputLayoutLimiteA.setError("Campo vacio");
        }
        else{
            textInputLayoutLimiteA.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        if(verificarVacio(editText_LimiteB) == true){
            textInputLayoutLimiteB.setError("Campo vacio");
        }
        else{
            textInputLayoutLimiteB.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        if(verificarVacio(editText_Error) == true){
            textInputLayoutError.setError("Campo vacio");
        }
        else{
            textInputLayoutError.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        if(verificarVacio(editText_Decimales) == true){
            textInputLayoutDecimales.setError("Campo vacio");
        }
        else{
            textInputLayoutDecimales.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public void setErrorFalse(){
    textInputLayoutFuncion.setErrorEnabled(false);
    textInputLayoutLimiteA.setErrorEnabled(false);
    textInputLayoutLimiteB.setErrorEnabled(false);
    textInputLayoutError.setErrorEnabled(false);
    textInputLayoutDecimales.setErrorEnabled(false);

}

public void initVariables(){
    metodo = new Metodos(editText_Funcion.getText().toString());
    a = 0; aAnt = 0; b = 0; bAnt = 0; xr = 0; xrAnt = 0; errorCalculado = 0; fa = 0; fb = 0; fxr =0; n = 1; filas = 0; boolDiverge = false;

    a = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(editText_LimiteA.getText()));
    b = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(editText_LimiteB.getText()));
    decimales = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(editText_Decimales.getText()));
    errorIngresado = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(editText_Error.getText()));
}

public void resolverBiseccion(){
    do {
        try {
            fa = metodo.resolver(a);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fb = metodo.resolver(b);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        xrAnt = xr; aAnt = a; bAnt = b;

        xr = ((a+b)/2);
        try {
            fxr = metodo.resolver(xr);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        errorCalculado = Math.abs(((xr - xrAnt)/xr)*100);

        if(fxr * fa < 0){
            b = xr;
        } else if(fxr * fb < 0){
            a = xr;
        }else{
            boolDiverge = true;
        }

        double [] celda = {n, aAnt, fa, bAnt, fb, xr, fxr, (fxr * fa), (fxr * fb), errorCalculado};
        n++;

        for(int j = 0; j < celda.length; j++){
            matriz[filas][j] = celda[j];
        }
        filas++;
    }while(errorCalculado >= errorIngresado);
}

public void clear(){
    editText_Funcion.setText(null);
    editText_Error.setText(null);
    editText_Decimales.setText(null);
    editText_LimiteA.setText(null);
    editText_LimiteB.setText(null);

    editText_Funcion.requestFocus();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_biseccion.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Biseccion">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarBiseccion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="@string/tittleBiseccion"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_Funcion"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_query_funcion"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="@string/stringHintFuncion"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_LimiteA"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_query_limiteA"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="@string/stringHintLimiteA"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_LimiteB"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_query_limiteB"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="@string/stringHintLimiteB"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_Error"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_query_error"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="@string/stringHintError"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_Decimales"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_query_decimales"
                android:layout_width="220dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="@string/stringHintDecimales"
                android:inputType="number" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPanel_Aceptar"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/stringTextButton_Aceptar" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonPanel_Nuevo"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/stringTextButton_Nuevo" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_result_biseccion.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".ResultBiseccion">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbarBiseccion"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:title="@string/tittleBiseccion">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/black">
            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hola, podrias agregar que error estas recibiendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola es verdad que no reconoce el simbolo de raiz cuadrada ademas imagino que te estan faltando parentesis para determinar donde cierra la raiz

proba cambiar esto:

```
√(x^2)+1 -tan⁡(x)
```

por esto:

```
sqrt((x^2)+1)-tan⁡(x)
```

y asegurate de usar bien los parentesis.

Ademas te dejo el [link a la documentacion de Djep](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/functions.html) donde tenes el listado de funciones que reconoce.

Comment: gracias, buena idea